# How to use two-factor authentication without iCloud to access my Developer Account

Tags: icloud, developer-program

[Macbook Pro 2014 Retina, MacOS 10.14.5, Xcode 10.2]

I need to download the installer for Xcode 10.1, but when I access https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_10.1/Xcode_10.1.xip, I'm land on the following page:

[image: Sorry, you cannot view this page.]

When I access my account, I'm presented with the following page:
[image: Your Apple ID needs to be updated.]

When I access the "Password & Security" view on my iPhone, I'm asked to log into iCloud, however I **do not use** iCloud.

Using my Mac, after logging into https://appleid.apple.com/account/manage, and attempting to use the the enable 2-factor option for my Mac, I get the following screen, requiring me to log into iCloud  /~(

[image]

What do I need to do to satisfy the requirements without touching iCloud?

Comment: Log into https://appleid.apple.com using your computer and enable Two-factor authentication there.

Comment: Thanks @NimeshNeema, that link helped.  However my question still stands...  I do not want to use iCloud, I don't want to log into iCloud <PERIOD>.   Cannot Google's authenticator or some other means be used to facilitate 2-factor authentication?

Comment: You need not log into iCloud. Once you have Two-factor authentication enabled, you can receive the verification code on your trusted device(s). If you do not have a trusted device (as you do not wish to log into iCloud), you can also receive the verification code via SMS.

Comment: When I follow the given instructions (see my updated OP), they ask me to log into iCloud.  My iPhone is already listed as a trusted device.

Comment: You have to use iCloud once to enable Two-factor authentication. You can log out from iCloud immediately after enabling 2FA. For instructions on how to receive the code via SMS see: [Get a verification code and sign in with two-factor authentication](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204974)

Comment: So not happy!!!  I don't want to use iCloud, not once, not ever.
Thanks for your help @NimeshNeema!!